# How to manually create a user and password in a database for my website

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I was following a login system tutorial and got minor kinks figured out. My next step is to create a manual user in my MySQL database so that I am able to login. I only need one user. The tutorial didn't show a registration part for it.

Here is the login.php code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {
     session_register("myusername");
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

     header("location: welcome.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: _"I was following a login system tutorial"_  if it's using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and not prepared statements / parameter binding, **find a new tutorial immediately**. Even worse is using plain-text passwords

Comment: If this code is the result of a tutorial, you followed a bad tutorial.  (Don't feel bad about that, there are *many* bad PHP examples out there.)  Your code is potentially open to SQL injection, and you're storing user passwords in plain text.  You're going to want to find a tutorial which (1) uses prepared statements with parameter binding and (2) uses PHP's built-in password tools (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php).

Comment: To answer your question though, you can either a) use your database tools (`mysql` CLI / PHPMyAdmin / MySQL Workbench / etc) to add a user record, or b) write a PHP script to perform the appropriate `INSERT` query and execute it only once

Comment: Looks like it's this tutorial ~ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm. I personally wouldn't use anything on that site

Comment: For those of you saying "find a new tutorial"... the *process* in the tutorial is probably fine. A *process* will work no matter the language, technologies, etc. used. It is a "how to do it".  That said, I agree if you change the statements to "don't use that code as a copy/paste basis" - and list the reasons why (most have done this, good!)

Comment: Thank you, I was just exploring my options.. I just needed one user so I figured I'd follow something simple. I'll keep searching. I really appreciate ALL of your responses.

Comment: @GSTO What is the version of PHP this is running from? You need to `@Funk` me to respond directly to me, or you can `@member` another. The version is important here for a certain function you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this SQL query:

`INSERT INTO admin ( username, passcode) VALUES ( 'testuser', 'testpassword' )`

Change `testuser` and `testpassword` to the username and password you want.

Comment: Why was this downvoted when it seems to answer the question?

Comment: @Dharman I provided a sample SQL statement that was compatible with OP's code which specifically stores passwords in plaintext. Hashing passwords, while technically the right thing to do, is tangential to OP's original question.